# Simple google-map app not working in emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm a newbie to Android development. I was trying to create a very basic simple app to use google-map features but for some reason, the map is not loaded as expected. Attached is an image which shows how it is loaded.

[image]

Below is my google_maps_api.xml. I have created a new Google Maps API key and is active.

```
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

    https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=9F:9B:0A:4E:CA:F7:7C:D3:83:42:BE:E3:91:18:00:6C:16:D7:B2:96%3Bcom.mycompany.googlemapsdemo

    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:

    Package name:
    9F:9B:0A:4E:CA:F7:7C:D3:83:42:BE:E3:91:18:00:6C:16:D7:B2:96

    SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
    9F:9B:0A:4E:CA:F7:7C:D3:83:42:BE:E3:91:18:00:6C:16:D7:B2:96

    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">**mykey**</string>
</resources>
```

Below us activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.googlemapsdemo.MapsActivity" />
```

and AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.googlemapsdemo">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.
   READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MapsActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.googlemapsdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.BundleCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I don't see any errors in Logcat. One interesting thing is that, whenever I try to zoom in/out or scroll up/down, app crashes but again no errors. I'm using

Android Studio 3.0
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Logcat messages
[image]

**Update 3:**
I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the below messages that I see in Logcat

11-14 11:57:18.471 2816-2974/com.example.mmuniyappa.googlemapdemonew W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

11-14 11:57:18.491 2816-2974/com.example.mmuniyappa.googlemapdemonew W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/x86

Also, when I try to zoom in/out or scroll up/down, Emulator crashes with a popup message

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: If app crashes, I can guarantee you there are errors. Make sure you are not swallowing any exceptions. Also when you say it is not working, it is hard to guess. But one thing to keep in mind while running in emulator is , you have to provide your expected coordinates to emualtor. It wont fetch the hosting pc address if you were expecting that by default.  And based on our map , your map is way zoomed out. Try to add zoom in moveCamera method  like , `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLocation,13))`

Comment: I installed the same app on samsung s7 and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Version meta data is missing in your manifest file.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I tried adding them in AndroidManifest.xml but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the API key is matching with the app ID, in the

[Google API Console - Google Cloud Platform](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: this is the Map sample from Android Studio, either the problem with the API key or the emulator has a problem somehow.

Comment: The map is partially visible, which means this has nothing to do with the API Key. It might be a network problem, or maybe you could try another emulator with another Google APIs system image.

Comment: I tried with different emulators Nexus 4, 6, 6P but no luck. When I installed this app on Samsung S7, it works fine.

Comment: ok one final solution : update your google play services in your installed SDK.

Answer (score 0):

With Refrence to [Google Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70424482)

**It has been fixed with Google API 27 image (rev 3). It should fix the Google Maps sample issue..**

If you're using API 27, it is a known issue that Maps API won't work there. Try a lower API level like API 26 for now

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70424482) they will re-open to examine.